# Using Python and OAuth2 with Twitter streaming API

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth

The Twitter v1 API is now defunct so I've been trying to use the Search and Streaming APIs to collate hashtag information. The Search API is rate limited, so if there are a lot of entries on a hashtag you will probably miss some. Streaming seemed like the way to go.

Using OAuth2 here is my (anonymized) code:

```
import oauth2 as oauth
import json

consumer_key = "<consumer key from twitter developer site>"
consumer_secret = "<consumer secret>"
oauth_token = "<access token>"
oauth_token_secret = "<access token secret>"
consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=consumer_key, secret=consumer_secret)
access_token = oauth.Token(key=oauth_token, secret=oauth_token_secret)
client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)

terms = json.dumps({'track' : 'twitter'})
stream_endpoint = "https://stream.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/filter.json"
response, data = client.request(stream_endpoint,"POST", body=terms, headers={'Content-Type':'application/json'})
```

The issue I run into is this always returns the following message:

```
>>>'No filter parameters found. Expect at least one parameter: follow track locations\r\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error is becouse using JSON data on

```
terms = json.dumps({'track' : 'twitter'})
```

You should write your code just like this

```
terms = 'track=twitter'
```

Comment: Have you got this to work successfully? I have left this code running for 30 minutes and it does not get a response.

Answer (score 0):

```
    USER = request.params.get('username', '00000')
    LIMIT = request.params.get('limit', '50')
    REQUEST_TOKEN_URL = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token'
    consumer_key    ='424245wfdsfa4'    
    consumer_secret ='afar234252523adsasd'

    if consumer_key is None or consumer_secret is None:
        print 'you need consumer_key & consumer_secret key'
        sys.exit(1)

    signature_method_hmac_sha1 = oauth.SignatureMethod_HMAC_SHA1()
    oauth_consumer             = oauth.Consumer(key=consumer_key, secret=consumer_secret)
    oauth_client               = oauth.Client(oauth_consumer)


    response, content = oauth_client.request(REQUEST_TOKEN_URL, 'POST')

    if response['status'] == '200':
        request_token = dict(parse_qsl(content))
    else:
        print 'Invalid response from Twitter requesting  token.........: %s' % response['status']

    endpoint = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=' + USER + '&count=' + LIMIT
    response, content = oauth_client.request(endpoint, 'GET')
    url = response['content-location']
    f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    response = f.read()
    return simplejson.loads(response)
```